# Javascript constructor: cant call inside func

Tags: javascript, constructor

Hi I defined this script:

```
var asdf = {                
        settings : {            
            scope : "blah"
        },  
        func1 : function () {
                alert('1');
        },
        func2 : function () {
                this.func1();
        }
}
```

why cant I use `this.func1()` to call a member func? Its strange because `this.settings.scope` works perfectly.

Whats the correct syntax? tnx

Comment: It seems to work... [Here's my jsFiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/SMqvz/)

Comment: Is this your actual testing code? Or by any chance did you create this example without testing to see if it demonstrates the actual problem you're having?

Comment: But did you test it to see if it illustrates your issue? We can't see how you're calling `func2`, but if you're doing `asdf.func2()`, then your code works.

Comment: Ok I think the problem was that this.func1() was called inside a 

FB.api('/me', function(response) {...

request, so that wasnt work.. Tnx for the fiddle :)

Answer (score 2):

> *"why cant I use this.func1() to call a member func?"*

You can, as long as you called `func2` from the context of `asdf`.

```
asdf.func2();  // alerts '1'
```

---

If you did something like this...

```
var fn = asdf.func2;

fn();
```

Then it wouldn't work, unless you manually set the context...

```
var fn = asdf.func2;

fn.call(asdf); // set the calling context of "func2" to the "asdf" object
```

Comment: Ok, but why do I need for the "asdf" context when calling func1 and not at this.settings.scope variable?

Comment: @zsitro: Your question doesn't show how you're using `this.settings.scope`, so I can't answer that. I'm just saying that if you do `asdf.func2`, then the value of `this` in `func2` will be the `asdf` object. Your question doesn't show any issue. If there's an issue to be solved, you need to demonstrate it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I take it from your tags that `func2` is a constructor? The reason is that `this` will be the object being constructed when a function is called using `new`. For example:

```
function Constructor() {
    console.log(this);
}

Constructor(); // window
new Constructor(); // instance of Constructor printed out
```

Instead, simply access `func1` as `asdf.func1` instead. It's safer if you *don't* use `this` in that type of situation, anyway; `this` can be bound to anything:

```
function func() {
    alert('What am I? ' + this);
}

func.call('A String! Weird.'); // Alerts What am I? A String! Weird.
```